# How to convert a sprint boot project with war packaging to jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a service **S** written using Spring Boot. It is packaged as a war. **S** acts as a mediator between application **M** (also a spring project) and a paid service **P**:

**M** <--> **S** <--> **P**

**M** calls APIs of **S** to use **P**.

However, after some recent design changes, a lot of utilities of **S** are either moved to **M** or removed completely, except for one API. Considering the deployment overhead to maintain a service(**S**) that just has one API, we have decided to use it **S** as a library instead of a separate service.

So now, **M** would just need to include **S** as a dependency (a library) in pom.xml file and it would use a method from some class of **S** to use **P** and just pass an object instead of calling the API of **S**.

To achieve above, I need to convert **S** to a JAR packaged library instead of WAR. There are a lot of articles about converting JAR to WAR, but none about opposite.

**Note:** I understand the best thing here would be to simply create a new maven project from scratch as no spring specific things are needed anymore. Also, a spring boot project has a lot of libraries that are not required, which affects the size of packaged JAR/WAR. So, just a maven project written from scratch would be lightweight and ideal but that would take some time. So, cannot take that road.

Comment: Remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Change type from `war` to `jar` in your `pom.xml` and well that is it. Then include this jar as a dependency in your other project(s).

Answer (score 0):

Create a [parent](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module) pom like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>M</module>
    <module>S</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

The S pom will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>S</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
     ..
     ..
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  </build>
</project>
```

The M project will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>M</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
      <artifactId>S</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  </build>
</project>
```

When you build the parent your finished jar should be in M. You may want a [fat jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

There will be no spring dependencies in these poms. You'll then need to fix any missing dependencies.